# How to use AES_ENCRYPT properly?

Tags: mysql, security, aes, collation

I'm trying to use AES encryption ([AES_ENCRYPT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) in MySQL) for user passwords but I came up with a bunch of different problems.

This is the SQL query that I use to store a new user into the database:

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES (
    '15',
    'John',
    'Doe',
    '123 Fake St.',
    AES_ENCRYPT('mypassword', 'mysalt'),
    'mysalt'
)
```

Where the salt would be a random string in a real case.

It works fine. I mean, I'm able to retrieve the original password. In this example, `AES_DECRYPT(user.password, 'mysalt') WHERE user.id = 15` retrieves `mypassword`. But I might be overlooking some things.

- Is it secure to save the salt along with the password? Aside from [security through obscurity thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).
- What is the best format to store the hashed password? I'm using
  VARBINARY but the stored string looks like `8�p�����_�Z�\`.
- And finally, how long should the password be and how long should the 
  salt be?

Thanks

Comment: You don't want to encrypt passwords, you want to crypto-hash them with an expensive algorithm like [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), or [scrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) — see http://security.stackexchange.com/a/6415/27154

Comment: @MarkFox I asked this question long ago. Nowadays I use [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/), which uses bcrypt if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, there is no actual need to reverse encrypt a password.  Having that ability inherently decreases the security of the system.  Instead, use an irreversible hash function.  I suggest SHA-256 (or larger) which produces a string result:

```
 SHA2 (CONCAT (user.name, user.password, 'some salt', user.id), 256)
```

I have also frustrated bulk [*rainbow tables*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) from being any use by rolling in other data always known at password validation time.

`SHA2` requires MySQL 5.5 or later.  If you are using an earlier version, `SHA1()` is nearly as good, and generally much better than `MD5`, `AES`, etc.

Comment: Good sugestion, an irreversible hashing function is probably better in this case. One last question, should the salt be stored along with the hashed password? And it has to be a different salt for every password?

Comment: @JohnDoe: If you do use a salt, there has to be some way of knowing what it is at password verification time.  Storing it is a pretty easy way.  Also, if using my suggestion of including `username` and `id`, a salt is much less important.  Without those, a unique salt value per user is highly recommended.  Otherwise a single rainbow table could be used for all users.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider using a password hash instead of a cryptographic hash. The goals are different. See https://security.stackexchange.com/a/6415/25424 for more info. Password frameworks like what are mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/516813 take care of a lot of details for you like the salting.

Answer (score 0):

You should not just encrypt the password in database, but store a *presentation* of the password in the database.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database) for lengthy explanation.